# Validar informacion desde el OnInit del formBuilder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Necesito un apoyo para realizar la validacion de los componentes que carga el forBuilder con pathValue.

En mi componente html tengo varias pestanhas y cada uno carga un formbuilder con los datos necesarios y los carga de forma correcta, solo que algunos atributos son para colocar datos de forma obligatoria y solamente valida al momento que realizo el POST del form.

Lo que necesito es que realice la validacion en el inicio del componente ya sea en el OnInit del ciclo de vida de angular u otro ciclo.

Para ello, estoy intentando utilizar el Server side de Bootstrap para informar los **.is-invalid and .is-valid**.

Necesito un ejemplo o tips ya sea en javascript para que mi form pueda ser validado los campos obligatorios e informarlo en el ap-vmessage.

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
      <label for="aluno-nome">Nome do aluno* <i class="far fa-question-circle fa-fw ml-1" placement="right" ngbTooltip="A alteração do nome do aluno só poderá ser feita via secretaria."></i></label>
      <input formControlName="nome" type="text" class="form-control" [textMask]="{mask: maskNome, guide:false}" />
      <ap-vmessage *ngIf="alunoForm.get('nome').errors?.maxlength && (alunoForm.submitted || alunoForm.get('nome').touched)"
                                                             text="O tamanho m&aacute;ximo do campo &eacute; de 120 caracteres">
      </ap-vmessage>
      <ap-vmessage *ngIf="alunoForm.get('nome').errors?.required && (alunoForm.submitted || alunoForm.get('nome').touched)"
                                                             text="O Campo &eacute; obrigat&oacute;rio">
      </ap-vmessage>
 </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, adjunta imágenes del front y código del TypeScript para tener una mejor claridad de tu escenario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es recorrer los controles del formulario, y marcarlos como dirty, para que se active y ejecuten los Validators de ese control, y así mismo se muestren los errores que deberian aparecer en HTML

Otra opción es al fórmulario FormGruop, llamar al método validate, y éste hará la tarea de validar todos los FormControl asociados el FormGroup.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar la validacion de Reactive Forms (Form Builder) de esta manera:

```
// Es lo mismo que usar formBuilder
  formulario: FormGroup
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.formulario = new FormGroup({

      miCampo: new FormControl("", [Validators.min(5)])
    })


  }
})
```

Esto lo pones en el ngOnInit y tienes validaciones al momento.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3jlsww?file=src/app/app.component.ts)